# Git GUI which allows to configure the pull button

Tags: git

I have a specific local branch, which shall pull exclusively a remote's master and ignore its tags. Namely, it shall do `git pull --no-tags remoterepo master`. I would like when the GUIs `pull`-Button does that. Does anyone know such a Git GUI? Bonus points for a GitHub Desktop and/or Sublime Merge solution. I am on Fedora Silverblue and use them as Flatpak.

Comment: `git fetch` does not operate on branches. Check your wording. // Check [the refspec for your remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt-ltrefspecgt).

Comment: @DanielB I meant `pull`, fixed. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have documented at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75800515/1658543) how I only fetch the master branch and no tags. In the  `.git/config`, I replace:

```
[remote "theirrepo"]
    url = https://somesite.com/someone/theirrepo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/theirrepo/*
```

... with ...

```
[remote "theirrepo"]
    url = https://somesite.com/someone/theirrepo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/theirrepo/master
    fetch = ^refs/tags/*
    tagOpt = --no-tags
```